# How to dynamically have label based on resource type for vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

i have a requirement where `autocomplete` comes from backend and it will have key called `filedId` based on that i want to show the label

if we click on **dynamic resource 1** btn  the label should be `city`

if we click on **dynamic resource 2** btn  the label should be `pinCode`

if we click on **dynamic resource 3** btn  the label should be `countryCode`

**Note:** i don't want to change the `data structure` / `json`

here is what i have tried

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default },
  data () {
    return {
      value: [],
      options: [],
      infoData:{},
    }
  },
  methods:{
    dr1(){
      let infoObj = {
        resource:{
          autocomplete:{
            fieldId:'city',
          },
          data:[{
             id:1,
             city:'Bengaluru'
           }],
        }
      }
      this.infoData = infoObj;
      this.options = infoObj.resource.data;
    },
    dr2(){
       let infoObj = {
        resource:{
          autocomplete:{
            fieldId:'pinCode',
          },
          data:[{
             id:1,
             pinCode:'560097'
           }],
        }
      }
      this.infoData = infoObj;
      this.options = infoObj.resource.data;
    },
    dr3(){
       let infoObj = {
        resource:{
          autocomplete:{
            fieldId:'countryCode',
          },
          data:[{
             id:1,
             countryCode:'+91'
           }],
        }
      }
      this.infoData = infoObj;
      this.options = infoObj.resource.data;
    },
   determineLabel(){
     let labelName = this.infoData.resource.autocomplete.fieldId;
     return labelName;
   }
  },
})
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Arial' }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timeline</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
  
  <button @click="dr1()">dynamic resource 1</button>
  <button @click="dr2()">dynamic resource 2</button>
  <button @click="dr3()">dynamic resource 3</button>
  <br/><br/>

<div>
  <multiselect
     v-model="value"
     label="determineLabel"
    :options="options"
     :multiple="false"
    :taggable="false"
  ></multiselect>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

here is codepen link to play with: https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/MWmrOBb

Still i did not find solution, please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Label prop in `<multiselect>` doesn't execute `determineLabel` by itself. it only gets computed or data option or a simple string. so you should put `determineLabel` in the computed:

```js
...

computed: {
 determineLabel() {
  let labelName = this.infoData.resource.autocomplete.fieldId;
  return labelName;
 }
}

...
```

Comment: not working still coming a empty you can fork codepen demo https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/MWmrOBb